# Bookmarking Reactives in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks

I am trying to find a way of saving reactives so that when I load from a saved state via bookmarking, my reactives are set at whatever I had before. Please find below a MWE:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(state){fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = 'LoadDataFromClippy',
               label = "Load data from clipboard"),
  bookmarkButton(),
  tableOutput(outputId = 'table')
)}


server <- function(input, output) {
  # Load data from clipboard
  LoadedData <- reactive({
    if(input$LoadDataFromClippy == 0){return()}
    input$LoadDataFromClippy
    return(read.table(file = "clipboard",header = FALSE))
  })

  # Render table for output
  output$table <- renderTable(({ LoadedData() }))

  # Bookmarking code --------------------------
  onBookmark(function(state) {
    state$values$LoadedData <- LoadedData()
  })

  onRestore(function(state) {
    LoadedData <- reactive({ state$values$LoadedData })
  })
}

# Run the application 
enableBookmarking(store = "server")
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Current Behaviour**

When you reload from the bookmark link, it loads the bookmark link into the table. This shows that it has loaded the state of the action button (so bookmarking in general is working), but is not loading / is immediately overwriting `LoadedData()` to the wrong thing.

**Desired behaviour**

Loads whatever I copied in previously. I would like to use the save to server method instead of save to URL as my non-minimum example is loading from an external file which I want to save in my bookmarked state.

I am also hoping this will help me saving `renderUI` objects.

**Things I've read**

I've read this: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/advanced-bookmarking.html which was good but didn't seem to follow through to `reactives` from `reactiveValues`.

Bests.

Comment: would it be an option for you to use `reactiveValues()` ?

Comment: Does that actually solve the problem? I am quite reluctant to change every reactive to a reactiveValue since the real version of the app is extremely large.

Comment: thats what i read from the linked article yes. For reactive functions i cant think of a possible solution, maybe smbdy else will find sthg

Answer (score 0):

Edits:

- use `function(request)` in `ui` (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html)
- create `reactiveValues` to store previous state; as per @BigDataScientist, bookmarking of states seems to work for `reactiveValues` currently
- essentially, save from `reactive` object, load to `reactiveValues` object
- in `LoadData()` definition, assign previous state if users haven't copied from clipboard yet

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    actionButton(
      inputId = "LoadDataFromClippy",
      label = "Load data from clipboard"
    ),
    bookmarkButton(),
    tableOutput(outputId = "table")
  )
}


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  # dummy value to initialize
  vals$sum <- NULL

  # Load data from clipboard
  LoadedData <- reactive({
    # return saved state if user hasn't copy from clipboard
    if (input$LoadDataFromClippy == 0) {
      return(vals$sum)
    }
    input$LoadDataFromClippy
    return(read.table(file = "clipboard", header = FALSE))
  })

  # Render table for output
  output$table <- renderTable(({
    LoadedData()
  }))

  # Bookmarking code --------------------------
  onBookmark(function(state) {
    state$values$LoadedData <- LoadedData()
  })

  onRestore(function(state) {
    vals$sum <- state$values$LoadedData
  })

  # Exclude the add button from bookmarking to avoid copying bookmark link to
  # clipboard
  setBookmarkExclude("LoadDataFromClippy")
}

# Run the application
enableBookmarking(store = "server")
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```